# Looping through map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looping through an array in react using map function to return option tags for HTML select tag. But it does not seem to work. Project_titles array is properly populated with data.

I have used same code in some other place and it is working there.

```
render() {
  <select
    id="sel4"
    onChange={event => this.setState({ project: event.target.value })}
  >
    {this.func()}
  </select>;
}

func() {
  this.state.project_titles.map(function(title, i) {
    return (
      <option key={i} value={title}>
        {title}
      </option>
    );
  });
}
```

Select tag should get populated with options but it is empty.

Comment: Maybe you should `return` from the function?

Comment: func returns void... just return the mapped array

Comment: `render` returns nothing and `func` also returns nothing.

Comment: Please could you try to put return instruction in your render() and func() function ?
```render() { return <select ... >...</select> }  func() { return ... ;}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. The issue with your code is you are not returning the final Options array from you func() function.

```
render(){
  <select
    id="sel4"
    onChange={event => this.setState({ project: event.target.value })}
  >
    {this.func()}
  </select>;
};

func = () => {
  return this.state.project_titles.map(function(title, i) {
    return (
      <option key={i} value={title}>
        {title}
      </option>
    );
  });
};
```